# ubuntu 12.04.3 lts process checking

Tags: server, process

How would i get the process id of a java process or know if the screen for the process of a minecraft server is on? just needing to get some help with this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite easy. fire up a terminal and issue the following command:

```
ps aux
```

you can also use grep. eg

```
ps aux | grep java
```

Comment: i mean more like if u have multiply java processes open?